# GRASS failed to import ESRI ASCII grid

Tags: grass-gis, esri-ascii-raster

I'm a new user of GRASS 6.4.3 and I wanted to import ESRI ASCII grid.

Raster file was unzipped, and in r.in.arc window I specified name for output, storage type etc.

After it has run, raster didn't appear on Display, and in Command Console there was next message:

Command 'd.rast map=39_03@Slovenija_WGS' failed

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did it fail to import or to display? That's not the same thing... And which operating system do you use?

Comment: Operating system is Windows 7. It's hard to say did it fail to import because in r.in.arc window it seems that it worked, also in layer manager there is layer, but it's invalid because I can't see properties or do anything with it. And it is not displayed in map display. Furthermore, there is mentioned message about error in command console.

Comment: Sidenote: We are going to remove r.in.arc in GRASS GIS 7 since r.in.gdal is much more powerful as pointed out in the harrikoo's comment. Additionally, please take a look at  http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

Answer (score 4):

First, you could try to find out whether the map was imported or not: use the `g.list` tool for that (GUI: File -> Manage maps and volumes -> List). Sometimes the GRASS modules add an imported map to the layer tree even though the import was unsuccesful and consequently the map is not there, resulting in the error message you refer to.

Second, if the map was not imported, you could try to import it using `r.in.gdal`, which supports a larger variety of map types. (GUI: File -> Import raster data -> Common import formats)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I solved my problem by installing Grass 6.4.4. which works perfectly.